# Library Barcode Scanner ZXing giving black Screen

Tags: android, camera, barcode

I am using the barcode scanner library of [ZXing](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/387).
It is working fine for all of my testing devices except 
a Nexus 5 running Android 6. 
Starting the activity it gives only a black screen and that's all. 
So I thought, ok, perhaps there are some compatibility problems 
and I downloaded the official barcode app published by ZXing. 
But it works fine on that Nexus 5.

So actually I am a bit irritated what I could have done wrong...

In the Android Monitor I get the message:

> android an error occurred while connecting to camera 0

I have searched for that status message but haven't found anything useful for me.

Has anyone a suggestion how to solve that problem ? 
Or a tip how to recognize the reason for the issue?

Comment: Does your app request the appropriate permissions?

Comment: Yes, it does:  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />. And that code is working fine on other devices (those had android 4-5). Perhaps it has something in common with Android 6?

Comment: It happened to me couple times before. You have to grant camera permission for your app manually (go to Settings->Application). Sometimes, specially when I uninstall the app by hand and then install it from Android Studio, it looses permissions somehow.

Comment: You have saved me al lot of time! Thanks

Comment: I have same "problem".
You can ask for and M permissions OnResume and when you handle response initialise ZXing lib.
 Also noticed that if user don't allow app to use camera and when finish activity you must check stopCamera method.

Comment: Had the same problem, actually needed to reboot device and it worked again(it worked before).

Answer (score 1):

Android 6 doesn't accept permisions from Manifest file
you should ask for permission on runtime.
somthing like this :

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M &&
                        getActivity().checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                            PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_CAMERA);
                } else {
                    mScannerView.startCamera();
                }
```

and then override onRequestPermissionResult :

```
@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        if (requestCode == PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_CAMERA) {
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                mScannerView.startCamera();
            }
        }
    }
```

hope this helps :)

Answer (score -2):

Same problem happened to me on a Nexus 5X under Android 6. The solution is to add Flashlight permission.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
```